# Automatically save the picture after clicking the mouse

Tags: graphics

this is my code：

```
interactiveBondTool[chemical_String] := 
  Module[{plot, coords, atomLabels, 
    bonds}, {plot, coords, atomLabels, bonds} = 
    EntityValue[
     Entity["Chemical", chemical], {"MoleculePlot", "AtomPositions", 
      "VertexTypes", "EdgeRules"}];
   If[Head /@ {plot, coords, atomLabels, bonds} === {Graphics3D, List,
       List, List}, 
    interactiveBondTool[{plot, coords, atomLabels, bonds}], 
    Missing["NotAvailable"]]];

interactiveBondTool[{plot_, coords_, atomLabels_, bonds_}] := 
  Module[{dihedralFromVectors, dihedralFromAtomNumbers, bondLength, 
    bondAngle, findAtomNearestToLine, bondInfoBox}, 
   dihedralFromVectors[{b1_, b2_, b3_}] := 
    Module[{n1, n2},(*http://math.stackexchange.com/a/47084/210969*)
     n1 = Normalize@Cross[b1, b2];
     n2 = Normalize@Cross[b2, b3];
     ArcTan[n1 . n2, Cross[n1, Normalize@b2] . n2]];
   dihedralFromAtomNumbers[{a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_}] := 
    dihedralFromVectors[(Subtract @@ coords[[#]]) & /@ {{a1, a2}, {a2,
         a3}, {a3, a4}}];
   bondLength[{a1_, a2_}] := EuclideanDistance @@ coords[[{a1, a2}]];
   bondAngle[{a1_, a2_, a3_}] := 
    VectorAngle @@ ((Subtract @@ coords[[#]]) & /@ {{a2, a1}, {a2, 
         a3}});
   findAtomNearestToLine[{v1_, v2_}, pts_] := 
    Module[{nearestFunc},(*adapted from this answer:http://
     mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28004/9490*)
     nearestFunc = 
      Function[{u}, 
       Norm /@ ({#/10, u - v1 - #} &@Projection[u - v1, v2 - v1])];
     First@Nearest[(nearestFunc /@ pts) -> pts, {0, 0}]];
   findAtomNearestToLine[None, pts_] := Nothing;
   bondInfoBox[pts_] := 
    Grid[{{"atom (atom number)", 
       Grid@Thread[{atomLabels[[pts]], 
          pts, {Red, Yellow, Green, 
            Blue}[[;; (Length@pts)]]}]}, {"bond length", 
       If[Length@Union@pts > 1, (bondLength@pts[[;; 2]])/100, 
        ""]}, {"bond angle", 
       If[Length@Union@pts > 2, (bondAngle@pts[[;; 3]])/Degree, 
        ""]}, {"dihedral angle", 
       If[Length@Union@pts > 3, (dihedralFromAtomNumbers@pts[[;; 4]])/
         Degree, ""]}}, Frame -> All];
   DynamicModule[{clicked = {}, atoms = {}, spheres = {}, 
     atomlabels = {}}, 
    atoms = Dynamic[Flatten[Position[coords, #] & /@ clicked]];
    atomlabels := 
     With[{pos = atoms}, If[pos === {}, {}, atomLabels[[#]] & /@ pos]];
    spheres = 
     Dynamic[Transpose[{{Red, Yellow, Green, Blue}[[;; 
          Length@clicked]], Sphere[#, 40] & /@ clicked}]];
    EventHandler[
     Row[{MouseAppearance[
        Show[plot, Graphics3D[spheres], ImageSize -> 500], "Arrow"], 
       Dynamic@bondInfoBox[Setting[atoms]]}], {"MouseClicked" :> 
       If[Length@clicked === 4, clicked = {}, 
        AppendTo[clicked, 
         findAtomNearestToLine[
          MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"], coords]]]}, 
     PassEventsDown -> True]]];
```

```mathematica
interactiveBondTool["Benzene"]
```

What I need now is that after "click", I can automatically save the picture

[image]

The part of my screenshot is what I want to save automatically, save it to the current nb file directory and name it in the format "pic-[n].png"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace you `DynamicModule` with the following code which contains a [`Button`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) and [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html):

```
DynamicModule[{clicked = {}, atoms = {}, spheres = {}, 
  atomlabels = {}, graphics, imageNumber = 0}, 
 atoms = Dynamic[Flatten[Position[coords, #] & /@ clicked]];
 atomlabels := 
  With[{pos = atoms}, If[pos === {}, {}, atomLabels[[#]] & /@ pos]];
 spheres = 
  Dynamic[Transpose[{{Red, Yellow, Green, Blue}[[;; Length@clicked]], 
     Sphere[#, 40] & /@ clicked}]];
 EventHandler[
  Grid[{graphics = {MouseAppearance[
       Show[plot, Graphics3D[spheres], ImageSize -> 500], "Arrow"], 
      Dynamic@bondInfoBox[Setting[atoms]]}, {"", 
     Button["Save image", 
      Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
         "pic-" <> ToString[imageNumber++] <> ".png"}], 
       Row[graphics]]]}}], {"MouseClicked" :> 
    If[Length@clicked === 4, clicked = {}, 
     AppendTo[clicked, 
      findAtomNearestToLine[MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"], 
       coords]]]}, PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

[image]

If you instead want this saving to happen automatically at click, just put that `Export` in your `"MouseClicked"` code:

```
{"MouseClicked" :> 
  If[Length@clicked === 4, 
   Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
      "pic-" <> ToString[imageNumber++] <> ".png"}], Row[graphics]]; 
   clicked = {}, 
   AppendTo[clicked, 
    findAtomNearestToLine[MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"], 
     coords]]]}
```